# Setup a Sharepoint Developer's Machine

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, development-environment

I am setting up a Virtual Machine for Sharepoint 2010 development (and then subsequently learn Sharepoint development).  I have a freshly installed Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise VM.

Are there any good blog posts or tutorials on what to install and how to configure all the Sharepoint stuff for development?  Or should I just install Sharepoint and SQL Server with the default options and that will be good enough?

Comment: default is good enough for the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an extremely good guide on this MSDN page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx

You don't need a separate installation of SQL Server, as the "stand-alone" installation option will install a SQL Server Express instance for you.

Don't forget to install the Microsoft SharePoint 2010 SDK from the Microsoft download centre:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f0c9daf3-4c54-45ed-9bde-7b4d83a8f26f&displaylang=en

And don't forget to also install Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Try
http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/05/tips-for-building-sharepoint-2010-base.html

You can combine it all into one machine if you want too.

The default options are sufficient unless they point out otherwise in the articles. For learning you can just "click next" for the installs and be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately doing a SharePoint 2010 dev build is a little more straightforward than previous versions.  However, here's guidance straight from the horse's mouth!

Happy SharePointing!

[MSDN Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Learn/Courses/SharePoint2010Developer/BuildSharePoint2010VM)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the below blog, all your doubts will be clarified.. You no need to install Sql Server seperately, while installing SP2010, it will install Sql server express by default.